# Does ContinueWith not handle Async callbacks?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I saw Stephen Cleary's blog about [Startnew being dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) and how [continuewith is also dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). I wanted to use it here to avoid having to write a try finally just to make a call to NSubstitute in the case of an exception. I found the Test passed when it shouldn't have and then noticed that the exception was thrown but it didn't make it out of the test to signal nunit.

Does ContinueWith act similarly to Task.Startnew with respect to async functions? I noticed this simplified equivalent will not throw the inner exception in Nunit 3.

```
[Test]
public async Task SimpleTest()
{
    await Task.Delay(10).ContinueWith( async t =>
    {
        await Task.Run(()=>{throw new Exception();});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContinueWith` does not understand `async` lambdas. You would need to use `Unwrap` in addition to passing a task scheduler.

> I wanted to use it here to avoid having to write a try finally just to make a call to NSubstitute in the case of an exception.

I don't understand this requirement. Why wouldn't this work?

```
await Task.Delay(10);
await Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception(); });
```

Comment: In the example the delay was just some "work". In my actual test that work could throw an exception so I would have to wrap that first await with a try catch and then call NSubstitute received(on a promise task function that requires await to be used, which is represented by the task.run in my example). Which seemed like it was going to be a bit more code then using continuewith.

Comment: To reiterate, a *proper* call to `ContinueWith` would look like this: `await Task.Delay(10).ContinueWith(_ => Task.Run(...), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();` I think `try { await Task.Delay(10); } finally { await Task.Run(...); }` is a lot cleaner.

Comment: If that is the case(I definitely am ignorant on complete proper continuewith usage), I would agree. I ended up creating a small helper library using await and try/catch/finally that is similar to javascript promises that lets me to something like doThis.finally(somethingelse). That way I avoid continuewith and avoid writing try finally all over my tests. Thanks for your help Stephen.